# Obtaining Facebook Rights Manager Matching Claim Data Via An API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Within our business we use Facebook Rights Manager to hold reference files which allows
us to track any copyright infringements for video. We can of course manage any matching claims
within the Rights Manager UI but given the volume of
content we have, this isn't very practical for us to do this manually.

My question is, does anyone know if there is a way we can obtain matching claims data via the Facebook API? We have looked at the pretty much all of the options in the documentation but have not been able to find anything which directly relates to extracting this type of data.

Any help or guidance to point us in the right direction with this would be very much appreciated - even if it's a definitive *"no that's not something which is available"*, just so we are aware of what options we have moving forward.

Thanks in advance

Comment: were you able to find an endpoint for this? i'm facing the same issue